# Why does Virtualbox's screen fail to redraw?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

After some inactivity on the host, typically after allowing the screensaver (on the host) to trigger, when I log back in (still on the host), and try to start interacting with my VM in Virtualbox again, I find that the screen fail to redraw.

By failing to redraw I mean that the screen is not just blank, but copies whatever is in the framebuffer from the previous window that was displayed -- i.e. when I switch to virtualbox, if I had Firefox open, I just get the (static) content of the previous window.

However, sometimes, if I wait some time, such as a few minutes, suddenly Virtualbox will redraw its screen and work as normal from that point. Half the time, no amount of time seems to make it start working again.

What is causing this? How can I mitigate it?

Host: Debian 9.13
Kernel (host): 4.9.0-15-amd64

Virtualbox version: Version 6.1.18 r142142 (Qt5.7.1)

Guest: Debian 10, with kernel 4.19.

What I've already tried:

Switching kernel versions on the host.

Upgrading to Debian 10.9 on the host.

Changing the video card in VirtualBox's settings.

Verified that the guest isn't running out of RAM (not even close).

Comment: The Virtualbox forum contains lots of such bug-report tickets. The most common advice seems to be to enable or disable 2D/3D support and also switching the video controller type (VBoxVGA and VMSVGA were mentioned among others). You might also try to reinstall Guest Additions. Some people just use workarounds when solutions are not found.

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing what was suggested? It is always good for the community to provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**What is causing this?**

Possible combination of your current resources and what you assigned to the VM.

**How can I mitigate it?**

You could try the following:

1. In *Settings* -> *Display* -> *Screen* ([source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=91145#p437892)):

   1.1. Increase the Video Memory.

   1.2. Change the Graphics controller (e.g., "VBoxSVGA" <-> "VBoxVGA").

   1.3. Enable Acceleration.
2. In *Settings* -> *System* -> *Processor* ([source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=92397)):

   2.1. Increase the number of processors assigned (but not all available).

In the meantime, please post:

1. Brand/Model/RAM of your PC.
2. The original configuration of the items above.
3. The *Settings* -> *System* -> *Base Memory* of the VM.
4. Do you have Guest Additions? Try installing it if not.
5. What is the video card on the host?